# Using timestamp with mysql and java

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to save a timestamp to a table in mySQL but whenever I look at the results it just shows 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

I assume I'm not using the timestamp right but anyways in my table I have a column named time and its property is TIMESTAMP

In my Java I have:

```
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(0);

String query = "insert ignore into time(time_now) values (?)";

pstmt.setString(1, timestamp);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

My database connection is fine as I have a lot of other information that's being uploaded to it with no problem, I'm just having trouble with the timestamp

Comment: Firsr you should use `datetime` instead and second - what is the format of the date you want to insert? It should be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

Comment: Well essentially I need just hh:mm:ss but TIMESTAMP in mysql forces date. If there's a better way to save just time I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, the `time` data type

Comment: I would still insert into it the same way,  with Timestamp?

Comment: You can use `CURTIME()` instead

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still confused. How do I use 'CURTIME()' in java to insert it into the database?

Comment: I changed my table so now TIMESTAMP is just TIME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("insert ignore into time(time_now) values (?)");
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(1, timestamp);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to store the time then use the `TIME` data type instead and to insert the current time **of the SQL server** use `CURTIME()` like this

```
 insert into your_table (time_column) 
 values (curtime())
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [java.sql.Timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html).  You are instantiating a new Timestamp object with '0'.

Comment: I tried adding the ints but it Eclipse would not accept it, only 0 passed without errors so I must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: It takes a long not an int in the constructor (Note: not a Long object type).